# Testing AndroidAnnotation EBean with JUnit

Tags: android, junit, android-annotations

I want to test my @EBean-annotated class:

```
public class ApiTests extends AndroidTestCase {

    private Api mApi;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        mApi = Api_.getInstance_(getContext());
    }
}
```

But I'm getting compiler error:

```
Warning:java: /Users/*****/api/Api.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'scope()' in type 'org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean': class file for org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean not found
```

IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) does not show any import errors.
How should I test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. API library should be added as "compile" into main project and as "provided" into the tests project.